# What will happen if unwind is applied to a field which is not present while using aggregation in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I am using a [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on a field in mongoose schema
According to the above link If field is not present then unwind will ignore input document
How can I prevent that so that result of query is returned without unwinding process even if field is not present i.e input document is not ignored

```
if a particular field exists   
  I want to do unwind and some more stuff (project and group) 
else
  I want input document no changes in this case
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to the above link If field is not present then unwind will throw an error

No, it don't:

> - If a value in the field specified by the field path is **not an array**, db.collection.aggregate() generates an **error**.
> - If you specify a path for a field that **does not exist** in an input document, the pipeline **ignores** the input document and will not output documents for that input document.

Here is a simple example:

```
> db.test.insert({a:[1]})
> db.test.insert({})

> db.test.aggregate({$unwind:'$a'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557362a17b97d77c38793c21"), "a" : 1 }
// no error -- but unwind only the document having the `a` field.
```

But:

```
> db.test.insert({a:2})
> db.test.aggregate({$unwind:'$a'})
// will result in error 15978:
// """Value at end of $unwind field path '$a' must be an Array,
//    but is a NumberDouble"""
```

---

As per your edit, if you need to keep documents with a *missing* field to unwind, you can `$project` a default value using [`$ifNull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/):

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557362a17b97d77c38793c21"), "a" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557362a57b97d77c38793c22") }

> db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: { a: { $ifNull: ['$a', [ null ]]}}},
    {$unwind: "$a"}
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557362a17b97d77c38793c21"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557362a57b97d77c38793c22"), "a" : null }
```