# MongoDB conditional lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to lookup a parent field by ID as part of an aggregation pipeline, but only certain fields have a parent.

so this code works fine when there is a parent, but breaks when there isn't:

```
    //get parent info
    {
        '$lookup': {
            "from": this.parentContentModel,
            "localField": "parent",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "parent"
        }
    },
    {'$unwind': { path: '$parent' } },
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954687/how-to-apply-condition-on-lookup-result-in-mongodb) it's fine if the lookup doesn't exist (though it doesn't work if the field name is empty or null, so I put in a placeholder):

```
    //get parent info
    {
        '$lookup': {
            "from": this.parentContentModel  || 'noparent',
            "localField": "parent",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "parent"
        }
    },
    {'$unwind': { path: '$parent' } },
```

Adding this doesn't fix it though, because then I need to unwind it, which breaks if the field doesn't exist. (If i take out the unwind, then it works fine when theres no parent, but then things with parents are broken because they need to be unwound).

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687607/what-will-happen-if-unwind-is-applied-to-a-field-which-is-not-present-while-usin) you can just project an empty array if the value was null, but $project drops all the old fields:

```
{'$project': { parent: {'$ifNull': ['$parent', [ null ] ]}}},
```

So I tried using $addFields instead of $project, but it still broke things with no parent field:

```
{'$addFields': { parent: {'$ifNull': ['$parent', [ null ] ]}}},
```

With that line added, it still only works for docs with a parent, unless I remove `$unwind`, which makes it only work for docs without a parent.

Comment: Have you tried `{  $unwind: { path: '$parent', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }` ?

Comment: Yup, that works, apparently that single flag was the secret. I don't really understand why, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$unwind` by default removes the document when the array that's being unwound is empty. You can change that behavior by using [preserveNullAndEmptyArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#behaviors) option:

```
{  $unwind: { path: '$parent', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
```